# How I can get text with desired height and width?

Tags: text, svg

I need to get text with desired height and width.
I tried to find something in documentation of svg but found only `font-size` and also I tried to use scale in such manner:

```
<text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="10996080909940" name="-1"
x="1782.9351809218"   y="-751.796133712862" width="1" height="1" style="font:Arial;text-
anchor:start;stroke:#000000" transform="rotate(0) scale(2 2)"> SOME TEXT </text>
```

But I get too big size of text and in place not where I need.

Comment: Not quite sure why you are after width/height. As an example using font-size, http://jsfiddle.net/emCqs/ can't you position/size like that. Or is there a specific requirement where you need to fit dynamic text to a shape, or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want the text to exactly fill an arbitrary width and height, then there isn't really an easy way to do it in SVG.  You can't specifiy a width and height on the `<text>` element.  At least not in the current SVG spec (1.1).

However there are several ways to achieve this effect with a bit of trickery.

One way is by using a transform, as you suggested:

```
<svg>

    <text font-size="10px" font-family="Verdana" transform="translate(99,400) scale(3.5,13.7)">SQUASHED TEXT</text>
    <rect x="100" y="300" width="300" height="100" fill="none" stroke="red" />

</svg>
```

A second way is by using an inner `<svg>` element and setting the viewBox to match the bounds of the text. You then set `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.

```
<svg>

    <svg x="100" y="100" width="300" height="100" viewBox="0.2 -7.3 86 7.3" preserveAspectRatio="none" overflow="visible">
       <text font-size="10px" font-family="Verdana">SQUASHED TEXT</text>
    </svg>
    <rect x="100" y="100" width="300" height="100" fill="none" stroke="red" />

</svg>
```

This way is more verbose, but it has the advantage that once you have found the correct viewBox for a piece of text, you can make it fit any sized rectangle very easily.  Just set the `x`,`y`,`width` and `height` of the inner `<svg>` to the size of the rectangle.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRgEF/3/